# running MSBuild command from power shell throws unexpected token in expression or statement error

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

If i run MSBuild from command prompt, it runs fine:

```
C:\Users\user1\Documents\testProject> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\Grounded.sln
```

I am trying to run same from Power Shell but it does not work and throws unexpected token in expression or statement error. What do i need to do:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\Documents\testProject> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\Grounded.sln
```

I guess i have to escape the arguments being passed but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMD.EXE the `%NAME%` is a placeholder for the environment variable `NAME`'s value. So in your case `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` expands to (usually) `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

In PowerShell, environment variables are not referenced this way. Rather, you'd have to write `$env:NAME` to reference the value of the variable `NAME`.

However, there is a complication here. Since the variable name "ProgramFiles(x86)" contains characters which are normally not allowed in a PowerShell variable name, here `(` and `)`, you have to write it like this: `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`.

Finally, you need to use the call operator `&`, because you want to treat the string with the full command line as an executable.

So in your case the command line should read this in PowerShell:

```
& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\Grounded.sln
```

Also consider reviewing [about_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.1) and [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1)